# Use of the .Equals() method in a LinqToEntities Where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm attempting to write a generic entity framework repository to reduce code duplication.  However, I have stumbled upon an issue with LinqToEntities.

Below is a reduced code snippet of my class:

```
public class EntityFrameworkRepository<TEntity, TId> :where TEntity : IDataStoreEntity<TId>
{
    private IDbSet<TEntity> m_entities;

    public TEntity Get(TId id)
    {
        var m_entities = Entities.Where(entity=>entity.Id.Equals(id));
        var retrievedEntity = entities.FirstOrDefault();
        return retrievedEntity;
    }
}
```

Due to the use of generics I have to use .Equals() and not ==.  However because of this LinqToEntities cannot generate the SQL required to query the database.  This results in a NotSupportException with the following message:

```
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

My current workaround is to .ToList() the DbSet and then carry out my query.  However, from my understanding this is not very efficient as it will pull all entries from the database.

Is there another solution to the problem?  If it helps I only intend to use primitive types anyway as an Id.  Alternatively, I will accept an answer explaining why my use of generics in this manner is poor.

Comment: Do your entities really have ID values with different types, or in reality are they all of one uniform type?  Don't try to allow the type to vary if there is no need for it to vary.

Comment: Are you only using this for finding entities by a primary key lookup? If so, look into the DbSet(TEntity).Find method; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: @kevin-d I've given your suggestion a go and it works a treat. Thank you. Did you want to supply it as an answer?

Comment: I wasn't entirely sure if you were only using it for PK lookups, but since that's the case; I have provided it as an answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only using this for a primary key lookup, you can use [DbSet(TEntity).Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx)